# Doesn't compile SCSS after update OSX to 10.13 (macOS High Sierra)

Tags: ruby, sass, koala

Koala version: 2.2.0

> Error message:
>   /scss/styles.scss
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in to_specs': Could not find 'sass' (>= 0) among 15 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError) Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/monstercritic/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0', executegem envfor more information from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:into_spec'
>   from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in gem' from /Applications/Koala.app/Contents/Resources/app.nw/bin/sass:17:in

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Step 1: Open terminal & run this code (this code for install homebrew)

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Step 2: run these code:

```
sudo gem uninstall sass
sudo gem install sass
```

done

Comment: Almost! Everything worked perfectly until the last step. "sudo" apparently doesn't open permissions enough.  

I ran SU... Then gem install sass.
System is back normal

Answer (score 1):

if this doesn't work try:

```
gem install sass --user-install
```

Bye